# Read Only Form Filling - PDFTron

Tags: pdftron

I'm using WebViewer [1] from PDFTron to fill Form Fields in a PDF on Web [2]. There's a way to make some fields in Read Only Mode, so the user will not be able to add text to textfield, check the checkboxes?

I found this page on the documentation [3] but it seems that I can only set document in read only mode, instead I want only custom fields in read only, users will be able to fill some fields and not others.
I found also this page [4] on doc to set fields to readonly but in my case on WebViewer it doesn't work, in my browser the viewerLoaded events never get called; I tried to put the code in another part of the code but nothing happens.

Are there some hints or some working code that you guys use?
Thanks, Alberto

[1] https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer 
[2] https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/form-filler 
[3] https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/annotations/annotation-permissions?searchTerm=readon#readonly-mode 
[4] https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/advanced/forms#set-fields-to-readonly

Comment: Great, but could you move your answer to an actual answer. That is the preferred way in StackOverflow (you can answer your own question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work with a modified version of this code [1]. The final result is:

```
$(document).on('documentLoaded', function() {
   var docViewer = myWebViewer.getInstance().docViewer;
   var annotManager = docViewer.getAnnotationManager();
   annotManager.on('annotationChanged', function(e, annotations, action) {

        // if the annotation change occurs because of an import then
        // these are fields from inside the document
        if (action === 'add' && e.imported) {
             annotations.forEach(function(annot) {

                if(annot.fieldName == 'read_only_field_name'){
                  annot.fieldFlags.set('ReadOnly', true);
                }
             });
        }
   });
});
```

[1] https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/advanced/forms#set-fields-to-readonly